# Python selenium: nested element finding

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, nested, recursive-descent

I'm trying to write a function, which returns a list of elements from any level of nesting from the html, containing the word 'products' in its text, case insensitive.

here is my function:

```
def __find_elements(driver):
    return driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                "//*[contains(translate(descendant::text(), "
                                "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', "
                                "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), "
                                "'products')]")
```

; for some reason, processing this part of HTML

```
<a class="nav-link main-navigation-link" href="https://www.leuze.com/en-int/products" itemprop="url" data-flyout-menu-trigger="e3e2319128d6464d8a025ac00823ce4e" title="Products">
    <div class="main-navigation-link-text"\>
        <span itemprop="name"\>Products\</span\>
    </div\>
</a\>
```

,
the function returns [] instead of the list, containing the following span element:

```
<span itemprop="name">Products</span>
```

QUESTION:
Could you please clarify, how to modify the function to return a list with the mentioned above span element, while processing the part of HTML?

Expected:
list with the element

```
<span itemprop="name">Products</span>
```

Actually happened:
empty list

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would change the XPath to

```
//*[text()='Products']
```

That will get you any element that contains the text, "Products". What other capitalization are you expecting? All caps or all lower case? If those are truly alternatives, I would change it to

```
//*[text()='products'] | //*[text()='Products'] | //*[text()='PRODUCTS']
```

or some variation only containing the spellings I was expecting. I think it's much more readable but that's just my opinion.

If those still don't work, you are likely running into a timing issue and you need to add a `WebDriverWait` or it may be that some/all of the found elements are not visible so their text value will be returned as empty string.

Comment: both XPaths: still return [],

        WebDriverWait(driver, SELENIUM_WAIT_TIMEOUT).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))

was/is in the code.

QUESTION:
Could you please clarify, how to check, whether some/all of the found elements are not visible so their text value?

Comment: You can test your locators in the devtools console. Press F12 to open it and then use `$$()` for CSS selectors and `$x()` for XPaths, e.g. `$x("//*[text()='Products']")` for your XPath. It will show how many matching elements were found. You can expand the search results and then click each element to see it in the DOM and/or hover it to highlight the element on the page. You'll have to visually inspect the element to see if it's visible or not. You could write some code using `.is_displayed()` and print the result from looping through the elements, if you wanted to do it that way.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']")
```

this will get all the elements within a span that have itemprop='name'

Comment: `.find_elements_by_*()` has been deprecated for a while now

Comment: This is also not an answer to the question asked

Comment: still return []

QUESTION:
What could be the issue?